# typecasting udp conversion issue

Tags: matlab, casting, udp, type-conversion

I am having a problem typecasting values that are being sent from my embedded board which is running a udp server to my matlab udp client which is not showing the correct value when I try to typecast the 4 bytes of data of the uint32 value. For example I send from the server a value(i.e. 1359151104), on the matlab side I receive this number : 1359200000. The code that I am using for this is : 
each mssgt takes all the of each corresponding place of the 4 byte value and makes an array to make the array of all of the values since I am receiving 153 values total, otherwise I wouldnt do the outSet#(this is so that I get one big array with all of the values ).

```
outSet1 = uint32(mssgt(1:4:length(mssgt)-3));
outSet2 = uint32(mssgt(2:4:length(mssgt)-2));
outSet3 = uint32(mssgt(3:4:length(mssgt)-1));
outSet4 = uint32(mssgt(4:4:length(mssgt)));
outSet = uint32(2^0*outSet1 + 2^8*outSet2 + 2^16*outSet3 + 2^24*outSet4);
```

For some of the bytes, I have negative numbers, I had this implementation before the above code but it also doesnt work.

```
for mm = 1 : length(mssgt)
    if mssgt(mm) < 0
        mssg(mm) = int16(256) + int16(mssgt(mm));
    else
        mssg(mm) = int16(mssgt(mm));
    end
end
```

I cant see what I am doing wrong. what is the error that is happening?

Comment: So you receive `mssgt` in MATLAB. Does that (in bytes) correspond to what you'd expect?

Comment: yea it seems that it is exactly what I should be if I compare it with the values of the bytes in wireshark.

Comment: And what's going on with `outSet`? that treats `outSet1` and the others as 8 bit numbers. Can you post the byte sequence for `mssgt` and the expected `outSet1`... numbers?

Comment: in the outset1 as mentioned above, it grabs all of the values that correspond to the first value of the four bytes which is one value of utin32 and places all of them into the outSet1. This happens the same for the other three outSet arrays(for their corresponding index, i.e.2,3,4) which I then do the calculation with all the of the four outSet# arrays and pass it onto to the outSet array. which automatically outputs the outset array of the 153 values that I expect from the udp. Mind you, the data length is then 612 bytes.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on because the code is not complete. What class is `mssgt`? Sure the message and how it's read don't mess with endianness?

Comment: mssgt is not a class, it is the array that is passing the 612 bytes of data that I am receiving in matlab. I will post the whole code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107992/discussion-between-zeemonkeez-and-aboogie).

Comment: If `mssgt` is your byte stream, why don't you use `typecast` to convert your data? Like `typecast(uint8(mssgt),'uint32')`, or, if the endianness is different, `swapbytes(typecast(uint8(mssgt),'uint32'))`